# Neutrino flavor and mass

Tags: oscillators, neutrinos

Neutrinos with specific mass don't have a unique flavor and neutrinos with specific flavor don't have unique mass.

Let's call the neutrinos with specific mass $\nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3$ and the neutrinos with specific flavor $\nu_e, \nu_\mu, \nu_\tau$.

According to the [subatomic stories of Fermilab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7H1M5DQa6g&list=PLCfRa7MXBEspXPQVseC0dDV8nWfQXe_6g&index=3)

\begin{align}
\nu_1 &= \{ \nu_e \} \\
\nu_2 &= \{ 0.5 \nu_\tau, 0.5\nu_\mu \} \\
\nu_3 &= \{ 0.3 \nu_e, 0.3\nu_\mu, 0.3\nu_\tau \}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\nu_e &= \{ \text{mix of } \nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3 \} \\
\nu_\mu &= \{ \text{mix of } \nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3 \} \\
\nu_\tau &= \{ \text{mix of } \nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3 \} \\
\end{align}

Since $\nu_1$  has always the flavor of an $\nu_e$, can we say that the mass of $\nu_\mu$ and $\nu_\tau$ depend on the mass of the $\nu_e$?

Comment: "according to ?????" What is your source for this ***obviously wrong*** non-fact?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7H1M5DQa6g&list=PLCfRa7MXBEspXPQVseC0dDV8nWfQXe_6g&index=3 (understanding neutrino oscillations like the pros)

Comment: iI is the channel of fermilab on youtube where they explain some particle physics stuff.

Comment: Don messed up, glibly. He should have provided ellipsis ... after $\nu_e$ to indicate the less than 50% components of the other flavors. He says "mostly" in words, to indicate [this](https://www.nevis.columbia.edu/daedalus/Pictures/numixing.png), where green is electron neutrino... He oversimplifies and ends up confusing you. Avoid physics videos...

Comment: The v1 neutrino doesn't only have the flavor of an electron neutrino I see...

Comment: [Right](https://www.nevis.columbia.edu/daedalus/motiv/neutrinos.html).  Popular science expositions not infrequently confuse more than explain...

Answer (score 2):

The {vectors} in your question are the rows and columns of the [neutrino mass mixing matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix), which is [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix). That means your statement (which you assign to a source) that

$$
\nu_1 = \{ \nu_e \} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \nu_3 = \{0.3 \nu_e, \cdots \}
$$

can *not* be correct. That's too much neutrino.

The middles of the allowed ranges (which aren't the same as the best-fit values, for reasons that require about an hour to explain to a new grad student) are

\begin{align}
\nu_1 &= \{ 0.67 \nu_e,\ 0.13 \nu_\mu,\ 0.16\nu_\tau \} \\
\nu_2 &= \{ 0.30 \nu_e,\ 0.33 \nu_\mu,\ 0.35\nu_\tau \} \\
\nu_3 &= \{ 0.02 \nu_e,\ 0.50 \nu_\mu,\ 0.47\nu_\tau \}
\end{align}

If tables of numbers make you a little cross-eyed, like they do me, a commenter linked to [this explanation](https://www.nevis.columbia.edu/daedalus/motiv/neutrinos.html) which includes the following graphic:

[image: neutrino mass/flavor mixing diagram]

(with $\color{green}{\text{electron}},\ \color{yellow}{\text{muon}},\ \color{cyan}{\text{tau}}$ neutrinos represented by the three colors.)

These are consistent with the values in your question, with two changes.  First, my $\nu_2, \nu_3$ are swapped relative to yours --- which may be a difference between "normal hierarchy" versus "inverted hierarchy," or may just an arbitrary labeling.  Second, your question has $\nu_1 = \{\nu_e\}$, where the reality is $\nu_1=\{\text{mostly } \nu_e\}$.

None of the flavor neutrinos $\nu_e, \nu_\mu, \nu_\tau$ has a well-defined mass, and the masses of the $\nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3$ are independent parameters.